# File not decrypting when program restarts, using the same encrypting key

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I have a simple program that encrypts and decrypts text from input gotten from a text file. When I encrypt and decrypt in one cycle, I get the desired result, but if I encrypt, close application then re-run application, this time decrypt, the process fails.

The decryption snippet looks like this :

```
string decoded, plainText;
string fileData((istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileDecrypt)), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

ECB_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption;
decryption.SetKey((byte*)key.c_str(), sizeof(key));
StringSource(fileData, true, new HexDecoder(new StringSink(decoded)));
StringSource(decoded, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decryption, new StringSink(plainText)));
```

When I run debugger in VS2010, I get error on the last line

```
StringSource(decoded, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(decryption, new StringSink(plainText)));
```

When I wrap a try-catch block around decrypt function, I get this error

```
StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
```

Not sure why it works if I encrypt and decrypt in one build, but fail if I try to decrypt without first encrypting first on the same run.

Comment: We've told you before about [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest you encrypt, write, terminate, restart, encrypt, read, and compare the two versions of the ciphertext.

Comment: @Beta - there's enough information available to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ECB_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption;
> ```

ECB mode operates on a full block size, and no padding is required.

You can pad it, but it does not look like you are doing so. The caveat is the plain text must be a multiple of 16, which is AES's blocksize.

---

> When I wrap a try-catch block around decrypt function, I get this
>   error
>
> ***`StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found`***

That's because you are padding it in:

```
StreamTransformationFilter(decryption, new StringSink(...)).
```

[`StreamTransformationFilter` has a padding parameter](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_stream_transformation_filter.html). As you probably realize, it is [`BlockPaddingScheme::PKCS_PADDING`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_stream_transformation_filter.html)

---

Try:

```
ECB_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption;
decryption.SetKey((byte*)key.data(), key.size());

std::string plainText;
StreamTransformationFilter filter(decryption, new StringSink(plainText),
                                  StreamTransformationFilter::NO_PADDING);

FileSource fs(filename.c_str(), true, new HexDecoder(new Redirector(filter)));
...
```

---

Other errata:

> ```
> ECB_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption;
> decryption.SetKey((byte*)key.c_str(), sizeof(key));
> ```

`sizeof(key)` is wrong. Use 16, 24, or 32. If the `std::string` is properly sized, then you can use `key.size()`.

And name you objects. I've seen GCC generate bad code with Crypto++:

```
ECB_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption;
StringSource ss1(fileData, ...);
StringSource ss2(decoded, ...);
```

---

And a quick warning....

ECB mode is usually wrong. I'm *not* saying it is in this case, or that you are wrong. But you might want to have a look at [`EAX mode`](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/EAX_Mode), [`GCM mode`](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode) or [`CCM mode`](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode). My apologies if this is more than it seems.

Even better, use a scheme like [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) or [Discrete Logarithm Integrated Encryption Scheme (DLIES)](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Discrete_Logarithm_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). The schemes are [IND-CCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability), which is a very strong notion of security.

When using ECIES or DLIES, your problem reduces to sharing the public keys. But you have that problem now with the symmetric keys, so its a lateral move for key distribution, and a win for encryption.